# Как узнать ip "белый" или нет?

Tags: boost, c++

Нужно программно определить является ли `ip` "белым". Какие программные пути для этого существуют? Не знаю может я все усложнил, но поискав, пришел к трем вариантам:

1) Узнать локальный `ip`, и распрасив его, узнать не попадает ли он под локальный диапазон

```
10.0.0.0/8
172.16.0.0/12
192.168.0.0/16
127.0.0.0/8
```

Локальный `ip` определятся так:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::host_name(), "");
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator it = resolver.resolve(query);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *it;
std::cout << endpoint.address().to_string() << '\n';
```

Является ли этот способ универсальным для всех видов (большинства) подключений к Интернет?

2) Узнать еще и внешний `ip` и сравнить его с локальным.

3) И последний способ. Этот код я скачал с [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674314/get-local-ip-address-using-boost-asio):

```
try {
    boost::asio::io_service netService;
    udp::resolver   resolver(netService);
    udp::resolver::query query(udp::v4(), "google.com", "");
    udp::resolver::iterator endpoints = resolver.resolve(query);
    udp::endpoint ep = *endpoints;
    udp::socket socket(netService);
    socket.connect(ep);
    boost::asio::ip::address addr = socket.local_endpoint().address();
    std::cout << "My IP according to google is: " << addr.to_string() << std::endl;
 } catch (std::exception& e){
    std::cerr << "Could not deal with socket. Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;

 }
```

здесь насколько мне говорит мой английский - подключение возможно только в том случаи если у меня "белый" `ip`. И если подключения будет удачным - то `ip` "белый". Правильно ли я понял? И какой вариант выбрать?

Трудность заключается в том, что я не знаю как тестировать. Ведь для этого необходим белый `ip`, чтобы попеременно запускать программу и смотреть что да и как работает.

Answer (score 3):

1. Просто отбросит все локальные адреса
2. -> 3.
3. Сообщит Вам - внешний айпи если подключение сотоится.

Вот тот, внешний айпи может быть как серым(NAT) так и - белым(BI-NAT). Отличие в том, будет ли Ваша машина "видна" по этому адресу из интернет.

А для того чтоб это проверить - надо чтобы удалённое устройство послало пакет на открытый на вашей машине порт. И этот пакет должен успешно дойти.

Увы, я не знаю операторов которые предлагают апи для отправки пакетов. Но есть вебсайты которые могут просканировать заданный порт.
Разумеется, надо открыть этот порт и ждать на него пакета.

К примеру: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/